# Parse Html and Javascript together on FPDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, fpdf

I want to generate a PDF using html (with php) and run javascript as well. I came across FPDF and I achieved both separately with libraries.

For html, [html parser](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php):

```
require('WriteHTML.php');

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->WriteHTML('You can<br><p align="center">center a line</p>and add a horizontal rule:<br><hr><button>LaLaLa</button>');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

This works. (*except the `<button></button>` tag; in fact `<a href="test.php">Test<a>` works)*

For javascript, [this example](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php):

```
require('pdf_js.php');

class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_JavaScript {
  function AutoPrint($dialog=false) {
      $param=($dialog ? 'true' : 'false');
      $script="print($param);";
      $this->IncludeJS($script);
  }
}

$pdf=new PDF_AutoPrint();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',20);
$pdf->Text(90, 50, 'Print me!');

$pdf->AutoPrint(true);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

When instantiating `$pdf` at first, both examples requires to call on their class - `$pdf=new PDF_AutoPrint();` and `$pdf=new PDF_HTML();`.

What should I do to combine both and place button in html with javascript action to use in FPDF?

---

Edit: Using this will only bring me one of the Outputs, not both (output behaves like return)

```
$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->WriteHTML('You can<br><p align="center">center a line</p>and add a horizontal rule:<br><hr><a href="lala.php">jfdskjfjksd</a>');

$pdf2=new PDF_AutoPrint();
$pdf2->AddPage();
$pdf2->SetFont('Arial','',20);
$pdf2->Text(90, 50, 'Print me!');
//Open the print dialog
$pdf2->AutoPrint(true);


$pdf->Output();
$pdf2->Output();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular scenario since the source for the `PDF_JavaScript` class is so small you could just add those methods to your `PDF_AutoPrint` class which would extend `PDF_HTML`.

```
class PDF_AutoPrint extends PDF_HTML{

  function AutoPrint($dialog=false) {
      $param=($dialog ? 'true' : 'false');
      $script="print($param);";
      $this->IncludeJS($script);
  }

  function IncludeJS($script) {
    $this->javascript=$script;
  }

  function _putjavascript() {
    $this->_newobj();
    $this->n_js=$this->n;
    $this->_out('<<');
    $this->_out('/Names [(EmbeddedJS) '.($this->n+1).' 0 R]');
    $this->_out('>>');
    $this->_out('endobj');
    $this->_newobj();
    $this->_out('<<');
    $this->_out('/S /JavaScript');
    $this->_out('/JS '.$this->_textstring($this->javascript));
    $this->_out('>>');
    $this->_out('endobj');
  }

  function _putresources() {
    parent::_putresources();
    if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
        $this->_putjavascript();
    }
  }

  function _putcatalog() {
    parent::_putcatalog();
    if (!empty($this->javascript)) {
        $this->_out('/Names <</JavaScript '.($this->n_js).' 0 R>>');
    }
  }

}
```

**Note:** Also check the license for `PDF_JavaScript` to make sure something like this is allowed.

**Note:** If you are using php >= 5.4.0 it would be better to implement something like this using [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)